# PermissionDeniedError: Failed to create a directory: /; Permission denied [Op:MergeV2Checkpoints]

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am unable to save model.
I am using Jupyter notebook.

```
epochs = 100
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn,)
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=valid_ds, verbose=2)
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Answer (score 6):

I also meet this problem.
My code is like this:

```
checkpoint_filepath = "/tmp/checkpoint"
```

And i changed it like this:

```
checkpoint_filepath = "./tmp/checkpoint"
```

I add a dot `.` before `/` and then it works.

So you can first cheak your callbacks path. Maybe is there something wrong in your callbacks path.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue

my code was like this:

```
ckpt_path = "E:\MachineLearning"
model.fit(dataset_train, 
      epochs=num_epochs, 
      validation_data=dataset_val,
      verbose=False,
      callbacks=[ckpt_callback])
```

I changed the path, it becomes like this:

```
ckpt_path = "E:\\MachineLearning\\"
```

I used a double slash instead of one, and I used a double slash at the end of the path.